# Use Cases for Task-Returning Hub Methods

Tags: task-parallel-library, signalr

What do you gain by returning Task types from SignalR hub methods, and what are the use cases for doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing asynchronous operations inside of a Hub method such as DB queries or web requests, it can be more efficient to use the [async/await pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) instead of blocking. SignalR will wait for the `Task`s returned from Hub methods to complete before sending the unwrapped result back to the calling client. SignalR will also make sure not dispose your Hub until the returned `Task` completes.

If you are not yet using .NET 4.5, you can use `Task.ContinueWith` or create your own `Task`s using a `TaskCompletionSource` if you are not working with a `Task` returning library.